# Is this really off topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, off-topic

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086369/how-does-a-browser-render-a-page-using-the-dom-model-constructed-from-html

One of the comments is that it is not programming related.

Possible answers to the question in question might be code snippets or links to a specific implementation i.e. IE and that wouldn't be off topic would it?

Comment: The OP's snide comment to Oded certainly doesn't help his case.

Comment: @jadarnel27 True, and I like Oded's response.

Comment: Matthew the question is now closed. Good job!

Comment: "i.e. IE" - just rolls off your tongue...

Comment: Just doing my duty.

Comment: Deletion is next.

Comment: @Lix I am trying to be more meta. Am I doing it right?

Comment: There's no such thing as doing it right on meta.

Comment: *"How does a browser render a page using the DOM model constructed from html?"* Well, the key to parsing HTML and getting it ready for display is understanding regex.  Once you've mastered that, you'll be halfway there, and it'll become quite obvious how to manage the rest.

Comment: To add to @AdamDavis comment, the rest is jQuery.

Comment: ... I thought that was how you summon Zalgo

Comment: @Matthew: Exactly.

Comment: H̡̫̤̤̣͉̤ͭ̓̓̇͗̎̀e ͎͉͖̌ͯͅͅc̸̤͓̞̱̫ͩͩ͑̋̀ͮͥͦ̊omes ̮̗̩̳̾

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hmm. No, I agree with the off-topic voters. This kind of behaviour is how a piece of software works in the general sense, which is more like [HowStuffWorks](http://www.howstuffworks.com/) (i.e. probably a question for [Super User](https://superuser.com/)). If you were asking how a specific part of the code *within* a browser works, then that sounds like a Stack Overflow question, because someone is running through  code and explaining that, but top-level functionality is more of a power user question than a software developer's question.

Comment: Actually, the question title looks specific and on topic enough to me. It's just too bad the question itself sucks and that the OP couldn't care less. I am almost tempted to reask it without giving him any sort of credit.

Comment: About the only on-topic bit I could see was the mention of a `DOM`. Asking "how does a web browser work" is way too broad a question for SO, imo. A question which is probably askable on [programmers.se] is "what software design patterns does (FF/Chrome) make use of?". At least then you have a ballpark discussion about the way to architect that kind of a system. But I don't think SO is generally suited to "how does `program` work?" questions.

Comment: True — I'm more concerned with the broadness of scope of the question myself. If I *could* dumb it down to something reasonably-scoped yet keep it interesting enough for web developers...

Comment: The question is gone now but it was very broad and kind of vague like 'how do most browsers render HTML...'

Answer (score 7):

This question falls foul of this paragraph of [What kind of questions should I *not* ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask):

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an
>   *entire book* that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Given that there exist both the Dragon book ('create your own compiler from scratch') and [WebKit for Dummies](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/111812720X), it's surely possible to imagine a 'create your own browser from scratch' book.